# How to get number of members in bots servers?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm new to making a Discord bot.

How can I get the total number of members in servers in which my bot is?

Comment: This has already been asked a few times on here, how come none of those solutions worked for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62115099/how-to-get-the-member-count-in-discord-py-rewrite Google before you ask

Comment: @JackArnold doesn't that mean that i have to put the ctx.guild.members inside a function with ctx argument which requires sending a message, doesn't it? how can i put it  in a function which doesn't require sending message and how would it look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the member count in discord.py rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62115099/how-to-get-the-member-count-in-discord-py-rewrite)

Comment: @RandomDavis the problem is that i want to put the number of members in bots status automatically. Al solutions i saw require ctx. which (as far as u know) goes only in functions for which is user input required and i don't want that. I hope you understand!

Comment: @stijndcl but how can i call the function to run itself?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with `call the function to run itself` but I provided an example that doesn't use `ctx`

Answer (score 0):

All guilds:

```
guilds = client.guilds
```

All members:

```
members = 0
for guild in guilds:
    members += len(guild.members)
```

This will yield duplicates (when people are in multiple servers). In case you don't want that, use a `set` & get the amount of items in that.

```
members_set = set()
for guild in guilds:
    for member in guild.members:
        members_set.add(member)
members = len(members_set)
```

Comment: Should I put this inside a function or should I write it separately?

Comment: You should put this wherever you want this to fire & where you want to use the member count... If it has to be the result of a function, but it in a function. If it has to be a command, make it a command. If it has to happen on startup, call it on startup.

Comment: I get that number of members in all servers is 2 which in reality is 15, but I run it on 2 servers so is that  a problem?

Comment: Yes, it is. You did something wrong. The other comment uses another built-in for this, consider using that instead if you can't get this to work.

Comment: When I add to it the part with set i get an error 'object of type 'int' has no len()'

Comment: You're not supposed to `add` the part with the set, those are 2 different options for you to use. You either use the first one, or the second. Also, you probably got that error because of a typo I made in my answer, which I'll take the blame for (& have corrected), but you still shouldn't combine them.

Comment: When I tried to use the first method the number of members I got was 2, and when I used second method I got 1. None of those numbers are correct. I used this inside client.command()

Answer (score 0):

Reffering to the discord.py documentation, `discord.ext.commands.Bot` has a `users` attribute which returns a list of all users within its member cache (due to recent intents change, if running on v1.5+ you will need to enable the member intent).

To get the amount of unique users, you can cast `discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_all_members()` to a set.

Comment: How would that look because when I print the result I get <function Client.get_all_members at 0x0000023C444FA160>?

Comment: get_all_members is a method, please refer to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_all_members)